# Singularity: Unable to push image to library: upload image blob failed: unauthorized

Tags: containers, singularity-container

I'm trying to push my own Singularity image to Sylabs. I've already made an access token as recommended here (https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.6/user-guide/cloud_library.html#pushing-a-container) and I've signed and verified my container as shown here (https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.6/user-guide/signNverify.html#signnverify). However, running `singularity push my_container.sif library://username/username/my_container:latest` gave me the following error

```
FATAL:   Unable to push image to library: upload image blob failed: unauthorized
```

Signing the image was successful as shown with this message:

```
INFO:    Signature created and applied to image 'my_container.sif'
```

Running the verification was also successful as shown here:

```
INFO:    Verified signature(s) from image 'my_container.sif'
```

So why is it that it's still saying that my image is unauthorized? Am I missing any important steps here?

Thank you!